# Publishing from R+knitr to WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, r, markdown, knitr

I would like to be able to write some R code in markdown (including images), compile it with knitr, and publish it into wordpress (including uploading the images to the blog, not as text in the post).  All from R.

I am thinking that [RWordPress](http://www.omegahat.org/RWordPress/) might have some useful tools for the job, though it wasn't updated for about two years now.

Do you think this is "easily" possible?  Does any of you have any suggestions regarding this?  Any lead will be appreciated.

(p.s: This question is my holy-grail of the year)

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but if you are an emacs user, org-mode and org-babel allow you to do just that (not in markdown, though), and org2blog provides a way to publish directly on a Wordpress blog via the XML-RPC interface.

Comment: If you can write html into your `newPost`, I don't see why this would be a problem. Once you knit your markdown document, it will make a .html. From there, you can strip out all the non-essential html and push it as part of a post.

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks - I think the biggest issue is with the images.  How to make sure to both upload them, and then <img> them correctly in the post.

Comment: Maybe this is of use: http://www.carlboettiger.info/2012/02/28/knitr-with-flickr-and-wordpress.html

Comment: of all the solutions I have seen so far, this one is probably the closest: http://wkmor1.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/rchievement-of-the-day-3-bloggin-from-r-14/ I might add a new function `knit2wp()` into `knitr` v1.1 after I have done some tests on `RWordPress`; images can be uploaded to Imgur by `knitr::imgur_upload()`. If anyone wants to contribute, please feel free to send pull requests :)

Comment: Here is another blogging solution from R Markdown, different from Wordpress. http://ramnathv.github.com/poirotBlog/about.html. It is still in beta.

Comment: Ramnath - thanks.
Yihui - that would be great! From gazing over the different blog post, it appears that it is very much feasible.  I will look forward to knitr V1.1.
With regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please test the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) (v1.0.10) of `knitr` and see if this works: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/wordpress/

Comment: Has wordpress changed how their XML-RPC api works with R because functions such as knit2wp (knitr) give me the following error: ``Error: faultCode: 401 faultString: Sorry, you are not allowed to publish posts on this site. ``

Comment: I get the same error using ``uploadFile`` or ``newPost`` from RWordpress

Comment: I get the same problem

Comment: I won't support WordPress any more. Please consider blogdown: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown