# Publishing R markdown files as blog post

Tags: r, wordpress, github, markdown

I want to publish a basic blog post like this:
[(Example blog post)](http://rpubs.com/hbat/6531) using my R markdown files.

But I want to publish it in Wordpress (not wordpress.com).

- The most promising solution seems to be [Yihui's function](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/wordpress/). I tried
  that but got many errors and stop trying. I'm using Windows and it seems like Yihui's knit2wp function works stable at Linux. (I deduct this from one of the comments in his page)
- Following posts did not help as well: [this](http://wkmor1.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/rchievement-of-the-day-3-bloggin-from-r-14/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660969/publishing-from-rknitr-to-wordpress).
- I tried to publish my markdown in GitHub like ([this](https://gist.github.com/jeromyanglim/2716336)) as
  mentioned in [Jerom Anglim's blog post](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2012/05/getting-started-with-r-markdown-knitr.html) (very informative blog post BTW). Can't figure out how to embed the GitHub file into Wordpress.
- I considered moving my whole blog to Jekyll as [one very good example](http://jason.bryer.org/posts/2012-12-10/Markdown_Jekyll_R_for_Blogging.html), but it
  seemed very daunting to change the whole blog structure.

None of the solutions worked for me. I give up. Copying and pasting code and formatting are very inefficient. I cannot align my r output properly.
Is there any other way that I did not stumble upon and possibly solve (or ease) my problem?
Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: +1 because I feel your pain...I tried many options as well. I ended up using `ruhoh` and don't regret it so far. I wrote a blog post about that [here](http://christophj.github.io/replicating/tutorial/how-to-set-up-a-new-blog-with-ruhoh-on-github/). But again, this is a derivative of Jekyll, so you also would need to change the whole blog structure.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://github.com/johnjosephhorton/md2blog

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "Pretty R syntax highlighter" (http://www.inside-r.org/pretty-r/tool)? It might be a nice temporary fix until you get something else working.

This code:

```
y <- 1:10
plot(y)
```

gets turned into this:

```
`<div style="overflow:auto;"><div class="geshifilter"><pre class="r geshifilter-R" style="font-family:monospace;">y <span style="">&lt;-</span> <span style="color: #cc66cc;">1</span><span style="">:</span><span style="color: #cc66cc;">10</span>
<a href="http://inside-r.org/r-doc/graphics/plot"><span style="color: #003399; font-weight: bold;">plot</span></a><span style="color: #009900;">&#40;</span>y<span style="color: #009900;">&#41;</span></pre></div></div><p><a href="http://www.inside-r.org/pretty-r" title="Created by Pretty R at inside-R.org">Created by Pretty R at inside-R.org</a></p>`
```

which, when imbedded in your html, displays like this:

y <- 1:10

[plot](http://inside-r.org/r-doc/graphics/plot)(y)

[Created by Pretty R at inside-R.org](http://www.inside-r.org/pretty-r)