# Publishing R markdown html output as blog post

Tags: wordpress, r-markdown

I want to publish a basic blog post like this: [(Example blog post)](https://rpubs.com/igmoreira/649116) using my R markdown files.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057118/publishing-r-markdown-files-as-blog-post), however no one seemed to have answered it appropriately.

Basically my problem sums up to this:
I ran an R markdown file that generates an html output (same as the one in the first link). However, when I try to copy the html code to my Wordpress blog, the images from the plots I generated do not load (they appear with this [Symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU4p0.jpg)

When I open the html in my browser locally, the plots appear as usual and they are encoded as base64 format so they are embedded in the html itself so it doesn't have to do with images in my local folder.

I would like to know if there is a way to resolve this issue or a way to post directly from Rmarkdown into wordpress (the RWordpress packages does not seem to work for me).

Comment: just a suggestion. You could host the file on [https://rpubs.com/](https://rpubs.com/) and link it from your wordpress page. I understand you want it on your page tho. Does the entire webpage load other than the images? Maybe you could host the images on imgur and link them into your wordpress page

Comment: Hi Daniel Thanks for your suggestions! I manage to solve it by changing the image encoding from base64 to svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to help anyone with similar problems, the solution I used was to change in R-Markdown the encoding of the image from base64 (default) to svg.

This is done by setting the option `dev='svg'` in the Chunk options.